# Where to find David Lau’s writings

Tags: sources-mekorot, rabbis, internet, ashkenazi, modern-times

Does the community here know where one could find any Halacha or responsa writings from Ashkenazi Israeli Chief Rabbi David Baruch Lau?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His halachic works can be downloaded via his Hebrew Wikipedia page ([link](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95#%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%95)).